# Copy rows from 1 table and Insert it to another in different Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with million records.

But, I just want to copy first 10000 rows and insert it to another table which is in different server in sql server management studio.

```
Server1
Db1
Table : table1

Server2
Db1
Table : table1
```

I want to copy 10000 rows from table1 in Db1 and insert it to table1 in Db2 from Server1 to Server2.

I know this query syntax, but i dont know how can i deal with different servers

```
INSERT table1 (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
  SELECT Col1, Col2, ..., ColN
  FROM table2
  WHERE ...
```

Comment: Are they on the same instance?

Comment: @ChrisPickford Please check my edit

Answer (score 2):

on your first instance, you can add a linked server to your second instance, and then reference it with 4 part naming .  You can add a linked server by expanding the server objects node, and then right click 'Linked Servers'

Then your query would look like

```
INSERT YourlinkedServer.YourDB.YourSchema.table1 (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
  SELECT TOP 1000 Col1, Col2, ..., ColN
  FROM table2
  WHERE ...
```

Your query could also be run by inserting the remote data into a local table

```
INSERT table1 (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
      SELECT TOP 1000 Col1, Col2, ..., ColN
      FROM YourlinkedServer.YourDB.YourSchema.table2
      WHERE ...
```

linked servers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: Should I create on my source or destination ?

Comment: Either is fine. If your create it on your source,  you can select from a local table on your source and insert into the linked server table.   If the linked server is created on your destination,  you can select from your linked server table and insert to your  local table

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers given involving linked servers, you can right click on your database in SSMS and use the Import/Export Wizard to move rows from one server to another.

In the wizard you can specify a query that will return only the top 10k rows that you want to export.

Comment: Yes, but I dont know, even if i have that same schema, it does not copy. Once i got a succeed message, but from source all the data were vanished and when I reopened, the data again came in source, but nothing in destination (may be because i am selecting 10k rows and it has few millions rows) ?

Comment: It works if you do it correctly.  Unfortunately I wasn't watching to know what you did wrong when you tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer to include how you would do it across a linked server. The 'Insert Into' statement allows you to insert into a linked server just as you would into another table on the same server, a temp table, a table variable, etc. As long as the select contains the correct number of columns and corresponding data types of the second table the following pseudo code works:

```
Insert Into LinkedServer.Db2.DbSchema.Table1
Select Top 10000 
   Column1,
   Column2,
   ...
From Db1.Table1
Where ...
```

Comment: I just want top 10000 rows

Comment: Editing the answer to include 'Top 10000' then in the Select statement.

Comment: I am really sorry, it is in different server in sql management studio, please check my edit.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: you are missing the schema db.schema.table

Comment: Updated the answer to address the change in the question and they 'why' behind the inserting through select approach. Thank you for the feedback!